# How to keep the previous values in array after new assignment?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array named `$arr = array`. Some of its keys has value, like this:

```
$arr['1'] = 'one';
$arr['2'] = 'two';
$arr['3'] = 'three';
```

Now I initialize that array with another arry, some thing like this:

```
$arr = array('4' => 'four', '5' => 'five');
```

But I need to keep the previous values. I mean is, when I print that array, the output will be like this:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($arr);

/* ---- output:
    Array
    (
    [4] => four
    [5] => five
    )
*/
```

While I want this output:

```
    Array
    (
    [1] => one
    [2] => two
    [3] => three
    [4] => four
    [5] => five
    )
```

So, How can I take care of old keys (values) after re-initialized?

Comment: What do you mean by this: _"I initialize that array with another array"_

Comment: Why cant you just [push](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_push.asp) to the initial array?

Comment: ^ This. Which is better than `array_merge` (because the index key are overwritten)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are your options detailed below: array_merge, union (+ operator), array_push, just set the keys directly and make a function that just loops over the array with your own custom rules.

Sample data:

```
$test1 = array('1'=>'one', '2'=>'two', '3'=>'three', 'stringkey'=>'string');
$test2 = array('3'=>'new three', '4'=>'four', '5'=>'five', 'stringkey'=>'new string');
```

---

**array_merge** (as seen in other answers) will re-index numeric keys (even numeric strings) back to zero and append new numeric indexes to the end. Non numeric string indexes will overwrite the value where the index exists in the former array with the value of the latter array.

```
$combined = array_merge($test1, $test2);
```

Result (http://codepad.viper-7.com/c9QiPe):

```
Array
(
    [0] => one
    [1] => two
    [2] => three
    [stringkey] => new string
    [3] => new three
    [4] => four
    [5] => five
)
```

---

A **union** will combine the arrays but both string and numeric keys will be handled the same. New indexes will be added and existing indexes will *NOT* be overwritten.

```
$combined = $test1 + $test2;
```

Result (http://codepad.viper-7.com/8z5g26):

```
Array
(
    [1] => one
    [2] => two
    [3] => three
    [stringkey] => string
    [4] => four
    [5] => five
)
```

---

**array_push** allows you to append keys to an array. So as long as the new keys are numeric and in sequential order, you can push on to the end of the array. Note though, non-numeric string keys in the latter array will be re-indexed to the highest numeric index in the existing array +1. If there are no numeric keys, this would be zero. You would also need to reference each new value as a separate argument (see arguments two and three below). Also, since the first argument is taken in by reference, it will modify the original array. The other options allow you to combine to a separate array in case you need the original.

```
array_push($test1, 'four', 'five');
```

Result (http://codepad.viper-7.com/5b9nvC):

```
Array
(
    [1] => one
    [2] => two
    [3] => three
    [stringkey] => string
    [4] => four
    [5] => five
)
```

---

You could also just set the keys directly.

```
$test1['4'] = 'four';
$test1['5'] = 'five';
```

Or even just make a loop and wrap it in a function to handle your custom rules for merging

```
function custom_array_merge($arr1, $arr2){
    //loop over array 2
    foreach($arr2 as $k=>$v){
        //if key exists in array 1
        if(array_key_exists($arr1, $k)){
            //do something special for when key exists
        } else {
            //do something special for when key doesn't exists
            $arr1[$k] = $v;
        }
    }
    return $arr1;
}
```

The function could be expanded to use stuff like [func_get_args](http://www.php.net/func_get_args) to allow any number of arguments.

I'm sure there are also more "hacky" ways to do it using stuff like [array_
splice](https://www.php.net/array_splice) or other array functions. However, IMO, I would avoid them just to keep the code a little more clear about what you are doing.

Comment: can you please add the behavior of `push_array()` to your answer?

Comment: @Sajad added array_push

Answer (score 4):

use `array_merge`:

```
$arr = array_merge($arr, array('4' => 'four', '5' => 'five'));
```

Well, as per the comments (which are correct) this will reindex the array, another solution to avoid that would be to do as follows:

```
array_push($arr, "four", "five");
```

But this would not work if you have different keys, like strings that are not masked numbers.

Another way is to use `+` in order to merge them maintaining keys:

```
$arr['1'] = 'one';
$arr['2'] = 'two';
$arr['3'] = 'three';

$arr2 = array('4' => 'four', '5' => 'five');

$arr = $arr + $arr2;
```

Comment: array merge will reset the keys if they are numeric (even strings masquerading as numbers). Which will re-index the array starting with zero. An array union will not.

Comment: This **will not work** as OP desired. It will change the keys as @JonathanKuhn said.

Comment: don't mean to point out the obvious, I just don't get why the need to provide an answer that has already been given.

Comment: I'm providing all the alternate ways to do it.

Comment: @AbraCadaver actually I wanted to ask, really why you deleted your answer?! It was great..., and I will use `+` for combining two my arrays.

Comment: You accepted a poor answer and mine got downvoted, so not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it, and keeps the keys of the array, is using [array_replace](http://php.net/manual/it/function.array-replace.php).

```
$arr['1'] = 'one';
$arr['2'] = 'two';
$arr['3'] = 'three';

print_r(array_replace($arr, array('4' => 'four', '5' => 'five')));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [1] => one
    [2] => two
    [3] => three
    [4] => four
    [5] => five
)
```